# Как срыть текст за padding при white-space: nowrap;?

Tags: html, css

Есть элемент фиксированной ширины, высоту менять нельзя, соответственно переносить текст не нужно. Текст в одну строку через white-space: nowrap; Скрываем текст из блока overflow: hidden; Но тогда он показывается поверх падинга блока. Возможно как-то поправить это? 
Внутренний блок нельзя создавать (

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  width:200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sapiente debitis quos reiciendis vitae aut pariatur labore atque perspiciatis eveniet ducimus! Corrupti reiciendis, quaerat enim animi voluptas corporis vel deserunt quam!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, при помощи псевдоэлемента `:after`

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  width:200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.block:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sapiente debitis quos reiciendis vitae aut pariatur labore atque perspiciatis eveniet ducimus! Corrupti reiciendis, quaerat enim animi voluptas corporis vel deserunt quam!
</div>
```